# Adding New Custom Query params in Cart Apis

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

We have requirement to add new custom query parameters in cart apis addEntries, updateEntries.
Please help us on the same how we can achieve this in spartacus storefeont  ?
Below is the use case mentioned for addEntry

**addEntries**:
    Existing:
        https://api.c39j2-walkersde1-d4-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/rest/v2/electronics-spa/
users/anonymous/carts/ca907c4f-7774-4b16-ba31-3cb1eec1eb82/entries?code=1992696&qty=1&lang=en&curr=USD

```
**Requirement**: new parameters (parentEntryNumber=&planSKU=3453333)
      https://api.c39j2-walkersde1-d4-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/rest/v2/electronics-spa/users/anonymous/carts/ca907c4f-7774-4b16-ba31-3cb1eec1eb82/entries?code=1992696&qty=1&lang=en&curr=USD&parentEntryNumber='1'&planSKU=3453333
```

Answer (score 1):

The OCC API endpoints are made configurable in Spartacus, using the configuration service. The [documentation describes this feature](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/) (Section "Configuring Endpoints").

You can find the default cart endpoint configuration [in the github repo](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/21d3b6cfd2f0c5921507879ebdaa14ea8804a472/projects/core/src/occ/adapters/cart/default-occ-cart-config.ts#L10).

Answer (score 0):

You need put your data for custom query in ngrx store. After you need extend `OccCartEntryAdapter.add`, `OccCartEntryAdapter.update`. In my example code `SomeFacadeService` select data from store.

```js
@Injectable()
export class OccCartEntryAdapter implements CartEntryAdapter {
  constructor(
    protected http: HttpClient,
    protected occEndpointsService: OccEndpointsService,
    protected converterService: ConverterService,
    protected someFacadeService: SomeFacadeService
  ) {}

  public add(
    userId: string,
    cartId: string,
    productCode: string,
    quantity: number = 1
  ): Observable<CartModification> {
    const toAdd = JSON.stringify({});

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    });


    return this.someFacadeService.getParams(productCode).pipe(
      mergeMap((params) => {

      const url = this.occEndpointsService.getUrl(
        'addEntries',
        {
          userId,
          cartId,
        },
        { code: productCode, qty: quantity, ...params }
      );

      return this.http
        .post<CartModification>(url, toAdd, { headers })
        .pipe(this.converterService.pipeable(CART_MODIFICATION_NORMALIZER));
      })
    )
  }
```